# disable (or change port) for web interface of neo4j embedded?

Tags: spring, configuration, neo4j

I have a number of small web service projects which use embedded neo4j 2.x.

Any combination of them might be deployed on a single tomcat instance, and therefore I need them NOT to all attempt to start a web service on port 7474.

Acceptable solution is either to disable web interface on all of them, or have each use a separate port. Is the first option doable via Spring configuration? If so, how?

I've tried with a config map:

```
    <util:map id="config">
        <entry key="enable_remote_shell" value="false" />
        <entry key="org.neo4j.server.webserver.port" value="7475" />
    </util:map>

    <bean id="graphDbFactory" class="org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory" />

    <bean id="graphDbBuilder" factory-bean="graphDbFactory"
        factory-method="newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder">
        <constructor-arg value="${neo4j.database.path}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="graphDbBuilderFinal" factory-bean="graphDbBuilder"
        factory-method="setConfig">
        <constructor-arg ref="config" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" factory-bean="graphDbBuilderFinal"
        factory-method="newGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown" />

    <bean id="serverWrapper" class="org.neo4j.server.WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper"
        init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService" />
    </bean>
```

but there's Jetty still binding the web service to port 7474... so I guess that

1. disabling the remote shell doesn't also disable the web admin interface?
2. org.neo4j.server.webserver.port is the wrong key, or
3. i've got the wrong recipe for the configuration (although this one seems consistent with all the neo4j 2.x Spring configuration examples I can find online)

If not, what do I set in the configuration to give each a distinct port number for the web interface? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this part

```
<bean id="serverWrapper" class="org.neo4j.server.WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper"
    init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService" />
</bean>
```